# Compose optional queries for for-comprehension in doobie?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, free-monad, doobie

I would like to run several queries in one transaction using a for-comprehension in doobie. Something like:

```
def addImage(path:String) : ConnectionIO[Image] = {
  sql"INSERT INTO images(path) VALUES($path)".update.withUniqueGeneratedKeys('id', 'path')
}

def addUser(username: String, imageId: Optional[Int]) : ConnectionIO[User] = {
  sql"INSERT INTO users(username, image_id) VALUES($username, $imageId)".update.withUniqueGeneratedKeys('id', 'username', 'image_id')
}

def createUser(username: String, imagePath: Optional[String]) : Future[User] = {
  val composedIO : ConnectionIO[User] = for {
    optImage <- imagePath.map { p => addImage(p) }
    user <- addUser(username, optImage.map(_.id))
  } yield user

  composedIO.transact(xa).unsafeToFuture
}
```

I just started with doobie (and cats) so I'm not that familiar with FreeMonads. I've been trying different solutions but for the for-comprehension to work it looks like both blocks needs to return a cats.free.Free[doobie.free.connection.ConnectionOp,?].

If this is true, is there a way to transform my ConnectionIO[Image] (from the addImage call) into a cats.free.Free[doobie.free.connection.ConnectionOp,Option[Image]] ?

Comment: since it wasn't mentioned in the answer, you should also be aware that you do not need to know anything about `Free` to use doobie. Just know that `ConnectionIO` gives you a monadic interface (flatMap etc) and that you can `xa.transact(myCIO)` into the task type of your transactor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your direct question, `ConnectionIO` is defined as `type ConnectionIO[A] = Free[ConnectionOp, A]`, i.e. the two types are equivalent (no transformation required).

Your issue is different, and can be easily seen if we step through the code step by step. For simplicity, I will use `Option` where you used `Optional`.

1. `imagePath.map { p => addImage(p) }`:

   `imagePath` is an Option, and `map` uses an `A => B` to convert `Option[A]` to `Option[B]`.

   Since `addImage` returns a `ConnectionIO[Image]`, we now have an `Option[ConnectionIO[Image]]`, i.e. this is an `Option` program, not a `ConnectionIO` program.

   We can instead return a `ConnectionIO[Option[Image]]` by replacing `map` with `traverse`, which uses the `Traverse` typeclass, see https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html for some details on how this works. But a basic intuition is that where `map` would have given you an `F[G[B]]`, `traverse` instead gives you a `G[F[B]]`. In a sense, it works similarly to `Future.traverse` from the standard library, but in a more general way.
2. `addUser(username, optImage.map(_.id))`

   The issue here is that given `optImage` which is an `Option[Image]`, and its `id` field, which is an `Option[Int]`, the result of `optImage.map(_.id)` is an `Option[Option[Int]]`, not the `Option[Int]` which your method expects.

   One way of solving this (if it matches your requirements), is to change this part of code to

   `addUser(username, optImage.flatMap(_.id))`

   flatMap can "join" an `Option` with another created by its value (if it exists).

(note: you need to add `import cats.implicits._` to get the syntax for `traverse`).

In general, some of the ideas here about `Traverse`, `flatMap`, etc., are useful to study, and two books for doing so are "Scala With Cats" (https://underscore.io/books/scala-with-cats/) and "Functional Programming with Scala" (https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala)

The author of doobie also recently gave a talk about "effects", which may be of use in improving your intuition about types like `Option`, `IO`, etc.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=po3wmq4S15A

Comment: Thanks for an excellent and informative answer. I got it working by using traverse. InitelliJ complains about "Expression of type doobie.ConnectionIO[models.Image] doesn't conform to the expected type G_[B_] - but no objections from the compiler.

The Optional was a typo - too much Java.

Comment: @janne That's very hard to avoid with IDEA unfortunately. The best method I've had is to sprinkle type annotations liberally to minimize the span of red squiggles.

Answer (score 2):

If I got your intention right, you should use `traverse` instead of `map`:

```
  val composedIO : ConnectionIO[User] = for {
    optImage <- imagePath.traverse { p => addImage(p) }
    user <- addUser(username, optImage.map(_.id))
  } yield user
```

You might need to import `cats.instances.option._` and/or `cats.syntax.traverse._`